# check which process cause high cpu utilization in last 24 hours

Tags: server, 20.04, cpu-load

Is there any possible command or way to check which process caused high cpu utilization in last 24 hours , because last night at 11:30 pm date:-30-nov-2022 we got alert that cpu utilization was high , so need to figure out which process cause high utilization.

Comment: Possible duplicate:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225073/how-can-i-see-what-process-spiked-cpu-usage-and-froze-the-system-a-few-seconds-a/

Answer (score 5):

**sar**

You can use [sar](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat). It’s included as part of sysstat. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

Next, enable it by editing /etc/default/sysstat and setting “ENABLED” to true.

Doing so monitors your system and generates a report every 10 minutes, rotating them out after a week. You can modify this behavior by editing the sysstat crontab at /etc/cron.d/sysstat, or by changing rotation settings in the sysstat settings at /etc/sysstat/sysstat.

You can generate a real-time report with the following command:

```
sar -u 1 3
```

sysstat will collect background CPU usage data every minute, saving it to /var/log/sysstat/. You can then import this data for analysis, using either a spreadsheet program or a custom tool like sargraph.

**atop**

An alternative is to use [atop](https://www.atoptool.nl/) which is able to store raw counters in a file for long-term analysis on system level and **process level**. By default, the daily logfiles are preserved for 28 days.
System activity reports can be generated from a logfile by using the atopsar command.

atop is available in the ubuntu repositories by: `sudo apt install atop`

Comment: Looks like sar does not collect information about individual processes but overall CPU usage.

Comment: @Jakob Point taken. Added a solution that offers logging on a per process level.

Answer (score 0):

## Top command

### Top in batch mode

```
top -b -n 1
```

### Then fish it out with Sed

```
top -b -n 1 | sed -n 8,8p
```

Comment: I want highest utilization in last 24 hours , I think your command works for current utilization.

Answer (score 0):

## Directly access log file

/var/log/syslog

### Simmer it down with grep

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep Nov | grep 30 | grep  11: | grep pid=
```

Answer (score -3):

## Process command

### Process Status (ps)

```
ps
```

```
    ps -eo lstart,pid,time,user,comm,pcpu  |\
    grep 2022 |\
    grep Nov |\
    grep pm |\
    grep 11 |\
    sort -n -k 10 -r |\
    head --lines 1
```

### Explaination

```
ps (Process Status)
-e (all processes)
-o (format the output)
lstart (long start)
pid (process identification)
time (time)
user (the user)
comm (command)
pcpu (cpu usage percent)
```

Output piped into another program, grep.

```
grep 2022 | grep Nov | grep pm | grep 11
```

Then sorted, by number and the column containing the CPU percentage

```
 
sort -n -k 10 -r
-n (number)
-k (column)
-r (reverse)
```

Then piped in to head to allow the first line through only

```
head --lines 1
```

Comment: Please explain how this should help.

Comment: It seems that you think that the process is still running. What if the load came from a "worker" process that is long gone ? A lot of services like Apache, databases and other applications starts sub-prepossesses / worker-threads to execute their work-loads, and these processes doesn't exists anymore. Your answer doesn't work.